# Adding margin to h3 inside a div moves the entire div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin, overlapping

Here's what I need: One div `sec-3` (orange) overlaps the other div `sec-2` (white). I  do this by giving sec-3 a `margin-top: -12%`. (Which is what i want). However the h3 in orange div is too close the image.

The problem: the `h3` that is somewhat close/behind the image is given `margin-top: 5%;` in `sec-3` BUT moves the entire div instead of moving the `h3` down.

Currently: The `h3` in sec-3 is behind the image of sec-2.

Here is what I looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8318.jpg

```css
.sec-2 {
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 11;
}

.sec-2 img {
    margin-top: 0%; 
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.sec-3 {
    margin-top: -12%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
}

.sec-3 img {
    margin-top: %;
}

.sec-3-headlines {
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sec-2">
    <h3>Say hi to Keeva.</h3>
    <p class="sales-copy">World’s most smartest personal assistant in your procket.</p>

    <!-- iphone 1 image -->
    <img src="img/img-3.png" width="90%">
<!-- <div class="grey-box"> </div> -->
</div>

<div class="sec-3">
    <!-- iphone image  -->
    <div class="sales-copy-wrap">
        <h3 class="sec-3-headlines">Get organized with events, tasks and notes.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="img/img-1.png" width="50%" height="">
    </div>
    <div class="sales-copy-wrap" id="normalize-margin-copy">
        <p class="sales-copy">Now more then ever it is critical for smart professionals to stay up to date with important deadlines.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not good idea !
create 3 section then . transform images with margin-top .

but for fix your problem you can give padding to .sec-3-headlines

Answer (score 0):

You could use [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position) to place the `h3`

```css
/* SECTION 2 */

.sec-2 {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 11;
}

.sec-2 img {
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}


/* SECTION 3 */

.sec-3 {
  margin-top: -12%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}

.sec-3 img {
  margin-top: %;
}

.sec-3 .sales-copy-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.sec-3-headlines {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 20px; /* adjust this value to lower the headline */
}
```

```html
<div class="sec-2">
  <h3>Say hi to Keeva.</h3>
  <p class="sales-copy">World’s most smartest personal assistant in your procket.</p>

  <!-- iphone 1 image -->
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x400" width="90%">
  <!--            <div class="grey-box"> </div>
 -->
</div>
<div class="sec-3">
  <!-- iphone image  -->
  <div class="sales-copy-wrap">
    <h3 class="sec-3-headlines">Get organized with events, tasks and notes.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x400" width="50%" height="">
  </div>
  <div class="sales-copy-wrap" id="normalize-margin-copy">
    <p class="sales-copy">Now more then ever it is critical for smart professionals to stay up to date with important deadlines.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```